# Animate camera position at a scrolling time

Tags: javascript, events, three.js, gsap

I am new to three js. I created a little project for my experience. The primary purpose of the project is to create a cube. Any side of a cube has a different color  (like in an image).

[image]

In scrolling time  (I mean event )  camera changed the position and show the full view of some side of the cube (like in an image).

[image]

My question is  How can I animate the camera position from one point to another?  I try some ways
to do that with the GSAP javascript library but it isn't working currently.

Thanks advance

My code

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls'
import gsap from "gsap";

const scene = new THREE.Scene()

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    75,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    0.1,
    1000
)
camera.position.set(0, 0, 30);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(45);
scene.add(axesHelper)

const geometry_1 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10);
const material_1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xFFFFFF, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
const face_1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry_1, material_1);
face_1.position.set(0, 0, 5);
scene.add(face_1);

const geometry_2 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10);
const material_2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xFF0000, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
const face_2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry_2, material_2);
face_2.position.set(0, 0, -5);
scene.add(face_2);

const geometry_3 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10);
const material_3 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x008000, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
const face_3 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry_3, material_3);
face_3.position.set(-5, 0, 0);
face_3.rotateY(Math.PI / -2);
scene.add(face_3);

const geometry_4 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10);
const material_4 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0000FF, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
const face_4 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry_4, material_4);
face_4.position.set(5, 0, 0);
face_4.rotateY(Math.PI / -2);
scene.add(face_4);

const geometry_5 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10);
const material_5 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xFFFF00, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
const face_5 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry_5, material_5);
face_5.position.set(0, 5, 0);
face_5.rotateX(Math.PI / -2);
scene.add(face_5);

const geometry_6 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10);
const material_6 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x4B0082, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
const face_6 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry_6, material_6);
face_6.position.set(0, -5, 0);
face_6.rotateX(Math.PI / -2);
scene.add(face_6);

window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll, false)
function onScroll() {

    if (window.scrollY / 10.0 <= 0) {
        camera.position.set(0, 0, 30);
        gsap.to(camera.position, {
            y:30,
            z:0,
            duration:5
        })
    } if (window.scrollY / 10.0 >= 30) {
        camera.position.set(0, 30, 0);
    } if (window.scrollY / 10.0 >= 60) {
        camera.position.set(30, 0, 0);
    } if (window.scrollY / 10.0 >= 90) {
        camera.position.set(0, 0, -30);
    } if (window.scrollY / 10.0 >= 120) {
        camera.position.set(-30, 0, 0);
    } if (window.scrollY / 10.0 >= 150) {
        camera.position.set(0, -30, 0);
    }

}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)

    render()
}

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera)
    controls.update();
}

animate()
```

Comment: Does anybody have suggestions related to this topic?

Comment: What you're asking about is called a "tween" animation, or "tweening." This breaks down the steps of moving from one position to another over a set time. There are several libraries that can help you do this with three.js that can be found by searching for the concept.

Comment: Thanks for your answer  TheJim01 . Can you suggest several libraries which use tweening?

Comment: Answers on StackOverflow need to be subjective, so providing recommendations is frowned upon. But if you put "tween three.js" into your search engine of choice, I guarantee you'll not only find libraries, but also tutorials and other resources for this concept.